# Prepend added record once to result table

Tags: jquery, append, prepend

I'm using jQuery Ui Dialog to add a record to a list of records. It works, but I want to prepend the newly added record row (tr) to the result page ONLY ONCE. It works but strange enough, the append and prepend and similar functions all do this for each element. I only want the added record to be prepended ONCE.

I've tried many things, including:

```
$( "#notes tbody" ).prependTo('#notes',response);
```

and

```
$( "#notes tbody" ).append(response);
$( "#notes tbody" ).prepend(response);
```

and so forth.

Any knows what will work?

Comment: what do you mean each element? Do you have multiple `tbody` elements inside #notes?

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle so we can see what's actually going on?

Comment: do you have multiple #notes elements?

Comment: I suspect the problem is with how you're setting `response`. Your last attempt should do what you want if `response` just contains one row. We're not going to be able to help without seeing more code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each response has some kind of class or id that can identify it from the rest, you could set up an if statement that restricts the response length to `< 1`

```
if($("tbody .response-name").length < 1){
   $( "#notes tbody" ).prepend(response);
}
```

Again, if new incoming responses have the same class or id that you are using in the if statement, then they will not be appended. It should work if you have some variable, the name of the record maybe, help determine the id.

For example

```
var recordName = // Some unique user input
<div id="response-" + recordName +></div>
```

It would be easier to help if there was some more context.

Here is a plugin I made to do this:

```
(function($){$.fn.specifPrepend=function(amountAppend,child,appItem){if($(this).children(child).length<amountAppend){$(this).prepend(appItem);}}})(jQuery);
```

use `$(".element").specifPrepend(amount, uniqueClass, itemToBeAppended);`